# how to connect the pretrained model's input to the output of tf.train.shuffle_batch?

Tags: tensorflow

In [classify_image.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py), the input image is fed with a loaded image in

`predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,{'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})`

What if I want to add new layers to the inception model and train the whole model again? Are the variables loaded from `classify_image_graph_def.pb` trainable? I saw that `freeze_graph.py` used `convert_variables_to_constants` to produce freezed graph. So can those loaded weights be trained again, are they constants? And how can I connect the input(`'shuffle_batch:0'`) to the inception model to the output of `tf.train.shuffle_batch`?

Answer (score 0):

The model used in classify_image.py has its variables frozen into constants, and doesn't have any gradient ops, so it's not easy to turn it back into something trainable. You can see how we remove one layer and replace it with something trainable here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

It's hard to generalize though. You'd be better off looking at some examples of fine-tuning here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception#how-to-fine-tune-a-pre-trained-model-on-a-new-task